# SwiftUI: Using List and ForEach to display model data of different types with an array of Strings

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-foreach

I want to display a dynamic list of items that come from model data. The problem I have is how to properly use ForEach to display a var that is an array of Strings. There are no compiling issues with the code, but I cannot get the List to display.

Here is the struct for the model data:

```
struct OrderInfo: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var id: Int
    var orderNumber: String
    var activeOrderStatus: Bool
    
    var pickupSection: Int
    var pickupStand: String
    var pickupItems: [String]
}
```

Here is the code for my View:

```
struct CompletedOrderPickUp: View {
    var completedOrder: OrderInfo
        
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Section")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(completedOrder.pickupSection)")
                }
                .pickUpDetailsTitleModifier()

                HStack {
                    Text("Stand Name")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(completedOrder.pickupStand)
                }
                .pickUpDetailsTitleModifier()
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Order Items")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .pickUpDetailsTitleModifier()
                               
                List {
                    ForEach(completedOrder.pickupItems, id: \.self) { items in
                        Text("\(items)")
                        Text(items)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the screenshot of what it produces:

[Screenshot with no items under "Order Items"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEjlD.png)

There's no issue with accessing the two other variables (pickupSection and pickupStand), which leads me to believe the problem lies with how to properly access the array of Strings within the data for pickupItems.

My friend Google has lots to say about ForEach and accessing data but not a lot about the combination of the two. Please let me know if I may clarify my question. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't have a `List` within  a `ScrollView` -- they are both scrolling components. If you remove the `List` wrapper, you'll see the items

Comment: So simple. I was digging in the wrong place. Thanks @jnpdx

Comment: Removing `List` displays the data. Is there now a way to display the array data as individual items/rows rather than a big block of text?

Is there an online resource that you can point me to? I've searched and searched, but no tutorial seems to address this specific request.

Comment: Why not using a List with section with header (the VStack with the 3 first text) and then ForEach items

Comment: @ScottyA You can style the data within the `ForEach` however you like. You can also make a new child component for each 'row'

Comment: @PtitXav Great thought. My limited understanding of styling Sections doesn't fit the look I want.

Comment: @jnpdx That's exactly where I'm stuck. Right now, the `completedOrder.pickupItems` shows a comma-delineated list of items that allows styling the **block of text**, rather than the individual items. I cannot figure out how to break them up to print individual lines. When I try to create a styled child view, I run into the original issue I had troubleshooting the ForEach: _Instance method 'appendInterpolation(_:formatter:)' requires that '[String]' inherit from 'NSObject'_ This points to my original assumptive question about the array of Strings. Any direction you can point me?