# SwiftUI: 3 attempts using ForEach to iterate array from model data produces entire array

Tags: arrays, swiftui, foreach

I posted [similar code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73308869/swiftui-using-list-and-foreach-to-display-model-data-of-different-types-with-an) describing a different issue that turned out to be a lack of understanding of ScrollView and List.

Working on the same project, I used `ForEach` to iterate over an array that came from a `struct` accessing model data, however the output is the entire array rather than the individual items.

Here is the `struct` for the model data:

```
struct OrderInfo: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var id: Int
    var orderNumber: String
    var activeOrderStatus: Bool
    
    var pickupSection: Int
    var pickupStand: String
    var pickupItems: [String]
}
```

This is my View:

```
    struct CompletedOrderPickUp: View {
        var completedOrder: OrderInfo
            
        var body: some View {
            ScrollView {
                HStack {
                    Text("Section")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(completedOrder.pickupSection)")
                }
                .pickUpDetailsTitleModifier()
            
                HStack {
                    Text("Stand Name")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(completedOrder.pickupStand)
                }
                .pickUpDetailsTitleModifier()
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Order Items")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .pickUpDetailsTitleModifier()

// 3 ATTEMPTS AT ForEach
                ForEach(completedOrder.pickupItems, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                }
                
                ForEach(0..<completedOrder.pickupItems.count, id: \.self) { items in
                    Text(self.completedOrder.pickupItems[items])
                }
                
                ForEach(completedOrder.pickupItems.indices) {
                    Text(self.completedOrder.pickupItems[$0])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[What my code produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo262.png)

From the many articles, questions, and tutorials I've read about arrays and `ForEach`, none help explain why in this use it produces the entire array instead of the items within. Each lesson assumes that `ForEach` displays the data on individual rows rather than in one big block.

[This is a hard-coded example of what I want it to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk1cd.png)

What am I missing? Any resource or direction to which you can point me?

Comment: Impossible to tell for sure but my guess is that the issue is in how `pickupItems` is populated. It looks like the value of each object is the entire line you are showing in the ui instead of each value in between the commas

Comment: @loremipsum Exactly. I hope the question is clear from the post: how do I not do this?

Comment: The error isn't here it is where `pickupItems` receives its value, this code is just displaying the value. Look for where `Cheeseburger, Cheesburger, Cheese Fry Bowl, 24oz
Draft Beer. 16oz Draft Beer` comes from.

Comment: @loremipsum That's it. The json file had been validated, but it was missing some "" marks. Thank you kindly.

Comment: I had in the .json file ```[“Cheeseburger, Cheeseburger, Fries, Beer”]``` instead of ```[“Cheeseburger”, “Cheeseburger”, “Fries”, “Beer”]```.

Comment: Glad to help that would make a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error where `pickupItems` receives its value, this code is just displaying the value.

Look for where "Cheeseburger, Cheesburger, Cheese Fry Bowl, 24oz Draft Beer. 16oz Draft Beer" comes from.

```
[“Cheeseburger, Cheeseburger, Fries, Beer”] //Array with 1 string

[“Cheeseburger”, “Cheeseburger”, “Fries”, “Beer”] //Array with multiple strings
```